# Print report with parameter

Tags: iccube-reporting

Having report with some constants and input parameters defined i'm trying to export it as a pdf. 
I'm calling GVI passing the "printReportBatchEx" action; the report expects an input parameter.
How to pass one or more parameters to the report with the print report batch mode?

Answer (score 1):

The report parameters are passed via the report URL (see [www](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/reporting/doc/ic3OpenReport.php#params) for more details). So assuming you have a report called my-report with a year parameter, you should print the URL (encode it properly):

```
http://localhost:8282/icCube/doc/ic3report?name=/users/marc/my-report&params={"year":"2010"}
```

as mentionned in the doc the 'params' URL parameter contains JSON.stringify() of the object containing the parameters of the report.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is that it seems not possible to pass parameter when making a HTTP POST request to the GVI service. 
I'm trying to generate Unattended reports using the printReportBatch (Chrome Headless server side printing). 
This means:
1) Create a HTTP POST request to GVI service
2) Pass authentication Headers (ic3-user and role)
3) pass inside the body of the request this parameters:
     action:printReportBatchEx
     reportPath:PATHTOREPORT     
     optionsJS: layout and printing settings
     ....
It looks like it is not possible to pass parameters.

Comment: I guess that is a different story as icCube Web Reporting is using most always POST requests.